# Fail to reuse_variables in tensorflow-r1.2

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I 'd like to do feature extraction on two sets of data, `x` and `y`. And I once successfully did it in tensorflow r-1.0 in the following way:

```
def conv_2d(input_, emb_size, num_filters, filter_width):
    return tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=input_, 
        num_outputs=num_filters, 
        kernel_size=[emb_size, filter_width],
        padding='VALID',
        stride=1,
        activation_fn=tf.nn.relu
        )
with tf.vairiable_scope('fea_extract') as scp:
    x_fea = conv2d(x, 125, 3, 3)
    scp.reuse_variables()
    y_fea = conv2d(y, 125, 3, 3)
```

It runs normally in `tf 1.0`. But in the `1.2` version, it got such an error: `ValueError: Variable fea_extract/Conv_3/weights does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable().`. Do you know why this issue happens and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Seems add one more variable scope in the `conv_2d` can solve the problem:

```
def conv_2d(input_, emb_size, num_filters, filter_width):
    with tf.variable_scope('conv2d'):
        return tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(
            inputs=input_, 
            num_outputs=num_filters, 
            kernel_size=[emb_size, filter_width],
            padding='VALID',
            stride=1,
            activation_fn=tf.nn.relu
            )
```

But I don't know why. Can someone explain the difference of the variable_scope and variable sharing between `tf-1.0` and after `tf-1.0`? Thanks!